# Printing floating point numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, show, floating

I have a function in Haskell which looks like this

```
type Price    = Int

formatPence :: Price -> String
formatPence a = show (a `div` 100) ++ "." ++ show(a `mod` 100)
```

so that, for example, if I input `formatPence 1023`, the output would be `"10.23"`. But I have a problem if I input `1202` because the output would be `"12.2"`. What should I add? Thanks :)

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps you wanted one of the various `show*Float` functions in `Numeric`?

```
> :m Numeric
> showFFloat (Just 2) 123.456 ""
123.45
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, he wants a function with type "Float -> String"
this avoids that step which makes this solution useless... what if he wants to print to a file.

Comment: For such a function, just abstract out the float: `(\f -> showFFloat (Just 2) f "") :: Float -> String`

Answer (score 10):

That's a standard problem that people have had ever since the infancy of computers. Hence it's perfectly well solved by the age-old [`printf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#v:printf) (which Haskell more or less copied from C).

```
import Text.Printf

formatPence = printf "%.2f" . (/100) . fromIntegral
```

Oh, to note... this has a precision problem for very large amounts, because `Double` (which is implicitly used for the division) doesn't have as high resolution as `Int`.

```
Prelude Text.Printf> formatPence 10000000000000013
"100000000000000.13"
Prelude Text.Printf> formatPence 100000000000000013
"1000000000000000.10"
Prelude Text.Printf> formatPence 1000000000000000013
"10000000000000000.00"
```

So if you're dealing with amounts of multiple trillion dollars, better not use this.

(I suppose if you were dealing with such amounts, you probably wouldn't ask this question here... and you wouldn't be using `Int`.)

To fix this, you can use your original approach, but still use `printf` to format the extra zero:

```
type Price' = Integer

formatPence' :: Price' -> String
formatPence' a = show (a `div` 100) ++ "." ++ printf "%02u" (a `mod` 100)
```

This will then work with arbitrarily ludicrous amounts:

```
> formatPence' 1000000000000000103
"10000000000000001.03"
> formatPence' 6529857623987620347562395876204395876395762398417639852764958726398527634972365928376529384
"65298576239876203475623958762043958763957623984176398527649587263985276349723659283765293.84"
```

Note that the manual div/mod leads in a problem for negative amounts, but that's easy to fix.

Comment: @SitiAisyah, Calling `printf` a perfect solution to anything is going way too far. I think the [`formatting` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/formatting) offers a much better replacement for C's `printf`. It avoids `printf`'s error-prone runtime format string processing nonsense in favor of a strongly typed approach; the downside is that you may get impenetrable error messages from the compiler when you goof up. I'd personally appreciate a nice big collection of really idiomatic, well-named `blah -> String` functions, but I'm not sure if anyone has one.

Comment: Agreed. I'm _not_ a great proponent of `printf` with its weird variadic signature, which is basically typechecked only at runtime; but for simple formatting of single numbers its quite sufficient and it's in `base`, so, for this particular task I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pad the part after the decimal with a zero.

```
twoDP :: Int -> String
twoDP v = if length str == 1 then '0':str else str
   where str = show v
```

You could write a more general padding function:

```
leadingZeros :: Int -> Int -> String
leadingZeros n v = replicate (n - length str) '0' ++ str
   where str = show v
```

Don't mess around with floating point versions of "show" or "printf" for this kind of thing: that way lies madness.