# Show Fractional without exponent part in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How to make Haskell show `Fractional` values without exponent part preserving leading zeros?

For example, command `show 0.0025` outputs `"2.5e-3"`. Is there a way to redefine this behavior?

Comment: You might want to try function `printf` from module [Text.Printf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html) ; expression `printf "%f\n" 0.0025` seems to return what you want. Of course it helps to be familiar with the printf() function in C.

Answer (score 4):

I tested first answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268789/printing-floating-point-numbers-in-haskell) , and it works

```
import Numeric
main = do
    putStrLn (showFFloat (Just 4)  0.0025 "")
```

Numeric module: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Numeric.html

Answer (score 3):

You can try `Text.Printf.printf`. The `%f` format should be what you want.

```
> import Text.Printf
> printf "%f" 0.0025  :: String
"0.0025"
```